# How do I close alert box in onClick method for button that gotten by inflating the layout?

Tags: android, layout, android-alertdialog

I create inflating Layout and I make button that i want to close dialog  when click the button.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.subtractalert,null);
```

the button code

```
    final Button delete = (Button) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
                        delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                // I want to close the dialog at here 

                            }


});
```

Thanks for all answer, tell me if you want more code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must first call [`.show()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#show%28%29) on the `alert` variable. You can then use [`.dismiss()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#dismiss%28%29) to get rid of the dialog, as long as your statements are within the same method.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// ...
final AlertDialog dialog = alert.show();
// ...
delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```